# Tick tack toe: Python numbers displaying differently in different contexts for no reason

Tags: python, python-2.7, tic-tac-toe

I'm not sure exactly how to describe this problem, so apologies if the title was insufficient.

I'm trying to make a piece of code that will put all possible tick-tack-toe boards (0 is blank, 1 is X, 2 is O) into a 2d array (list of lists). I've successfully found a way to do this:

```
import math

boxes = []

for m in range (0, 19683):
    boxes.append([m%3, int(math.floor((m%9)/3))])

print(boxes)
```

And it works. But instead of typing out the next seven list items, I thought it would be easier to iterate over them like so:

```
boxes = []

for m in range (0, 19683):
    boxes.append([])

    for s in range (0,9):
        boxes[m].append(int(math.floor((m%(3**(m+1)))/(3**m))))

print(boxes)
```

and it just gave me a big array of zeros! I have no idea why changing it to iteration would do this; I tried with both ** and pow(). DOes anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I think in your second example you could have meant:

```
boxes[m].append(int(math.floor((m%(3**(s+1)))/(3**s))))
```

Also, you can utilise [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to achieve the same kind of outcome:

```
boxes = list(product([0, 1, 2], repeat=9))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at that inner expression:

```
math.floor(m%(3**(m+1)))/(3**m)
```

The numerator is simply `m`: you take it modulus `3^(m+1)`, which will be larger than `m`.  The next step is then `m / (3**m)` -- taken as an integer, this is 0.

In short, your algebra is off.

I recommend that you use `itertools.product` to get the output you want.